# Updating ID fields in one table in relation to primary keys in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

This problem has been bugging me for quite some time. Say I have a database schema as follows:

Stock(**ID**, Book_ID, Meat_ID, Drink_ID)

Book(**Book_ID**, Book_Title, Book_Price, Book_Rating)

Food(**Food_ID**, Food_Name, Food_Price)

Drink(**Drink_ID**, Drink_Name, Drink_Price, Drink_Rarity)

Along with a flat file table that contains all fields except Book_ID, Meat_ID, Drink_ID:
FullData(**ID**, Book_Title, Book_Price, Book_Rating, Food_Name, Food_Price, Drink_Name, Drink_Price, Drink_Rarity)

How would I go about updating the Stock table with the IDs from my Book, Food and Drink tables in relation to the flat file Data table? That is to say, having the stock table in a way that it keeps track of the three IDs (hopefully adhering to 3NF)?

For example: 
Book row:

```
5, "Harry Potter", $10.00, 4
```

Food row:

```
2, "Beef", $5.00
```

Drink row:

```
7, "Cola", $3.00, common
```

Flat file row:

```
10, "Harry Potter", $10.00, 4, Beef, $5.00, "Cola", $3.00, common
```

Stock row, which combines the three:

```
10, 5, 2, 7
```

I've tried using INSERT INTO or UPDATE statements, but I'm confused if they are the right approach. I'm also wondering if this is also bad schema design.

Comment: there is any relation b/w book, food, drink ?

Comment: They are all part of the stock in a hypothetical shop. Maybe this wasn't the best example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already have inserted the `book`, `food` and `drink` entries into their respective tables.

In such a case, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO stock (book_id, meat_id, drink_id) 
SELECT (select b.id from book b where b.name = ff.book_title),
       (select f.id from food f where f.name = ff.food_name),
       (select d.id from drink d where d.name == ff.drink_name)
  FROM <flat_file_table> ff;
```

If there are no records to be found or possible `null` values for a given `name`, you can use `join` clause. Which will fetch only the `not null` values in the `SELECT` clause. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO stock (book_id, meat_id, drink_id) 
SELECT b.id, f.id, d.id
  FROM <flat_file_table> ff 
  JOIN book b ON ff.book_title = b.name 
  JOIN food f ON ff.food_name = f.name
  JOIN drink d ON ff.drink_name = d.name;
```

Comment: Is that syntax correct? I get an error stating that the operand should only contain 1 columns.

Comment: I tried separating them like so: `INSERT INTO stock (book_id) SELECT (select b.id from Book b where b.book_title = f.book_title) from FullData f` which did process but made all the book_id values in Stock be null.

Comment: @SmashingGood: Oops, I had added an extra `)` braces. Edited it now.

Comment: do you have any comment about the null values?

Comment: If no entry is found for a corresponding `book`, `food` or `drink` `name`, then a `null` value will be assigned to its corresponding `id` column. As simple as that. What are you looking for specifically here?

Comment: I'm hoping to get `book_id`, `meat_id` and `drink_id` to show up in a row in Stock as not null values. There shouldn't be any null values in the primary keys, though. I'll have to go back and check.

Comment: If you think there might be `null` values or no record found for a given `name`, then you can use the `JOIN` clause. Updated it in my answer.